# ASP.NET MVC 4 edit/delete operation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have some question regarding to edit/delete operation via asp.net mvc or web applications in general.

Lets say i have the following url to delete or edit records : app/delete/5, app/edit/5 to edit or delete record with id 5.

When calling the link, a confirmation page is loaded via HTTP GET and the edit/delete operation itself is done via HTTP POST.

Once user knows the link, how can i prevent him from calling any other app/delete or app/edit for records he does not own or is not permitted to edit/delete? Example: app/delete/7312

What do i have to put in my controller action that the user can only fetch the confirmation page via GET for the records he is permitted to execute an edit/delete?

Best regards
marc

Comment: By implementing authentication and authorization.

Comment: Look at the use of the `[Authorize]` attribute

Comment: `[Authorize]` only works if you can assign a set of allowed user roles to the action. But OP wants to prohibit deletion depending on the owner of the data.

Comment: Thanks Georg thats right. I'm already aware of [Authorize] and using it in my app to prevent users from accessing whole controllers i.e admin area. I want to know if there is a way framework can do what i want or if i have to manually implement these checks in my controller or via a self written service.

Answer (score 0):

Okay at first I posted a simpler answer but I didn't understand the question.  You are going to need two things.  A way to know who created what in the system, and then some business logic in the delete action checking if the current user is equal to the user who created it. I would suggest this inheritable class that i use to track ownership of an object:

```
public class BaseEntity
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
        [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
        public string UserCreated { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date Modified")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? DateModified { get; set; }
        public string UserModified { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your database context class, you can overwrite save changes to automatically track these things whenever a user in the system saves something t o populate those fields.  This is handy because you don't have to go into Create, Edit, etc. and manually link this up.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is BaseEntity && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));
            var currentUsername = HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.User != null
                ? Users.Find(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()).Name
                : "Anonymous";

            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                    ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UserCreated = currentUsername;
                }

                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).DateModified = DateTime.Now;
                ((BaseEntity)entity.Entity).UserModified = currentUsername;
            }
            return base.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Then finally, to actually achieve your functionality, you can in your controller's delete action only let the delete go through if Users.Find(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserID()).name is equal to the name of whoever created the model.

I know this is a lot, if you have questions please comment I'll check in.